# This script should be placing a GameObject at current mouse position but is instead placing at 0,0,0 in C# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class TowerPlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tower;
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            PlaceTower();
        }
    }

    private void PlaceTower()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        GameObject newTower = Instantiate(tower, new Vector3(hit.point.x, 10f, hit.point.z), Quaternion.identity);
        print(Input.mousePosition);
    }
}
```

As you can see its basic. I cannot figure this out.

Whenever I click I print out the current mouse coordinates and they are correct. I assume there is something wrong with the `GameObject newTower = Instantiate(tower, new Vector3(hit.point.x, 10f, hit.point.z),` section but I dont know what.

Comment: Where do you set the coordinates in `hit`? From the code you posted it's never set.

Comment: Oh dear, you have cracked it, a fresh set of eyes, I need ' if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit))' to store the info in hit, thanks